# Wallpaper gif Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo este código:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by jreese on 7/12/2015.
 */
public class GIFWallpaperService extends WallpaperService{
    //static final String TAG = "gifService";
    static final String TAG="gifWallpaper";
    static final Handler gifHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        try {
            return new GifEngine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error Creando Motor", e);
            stopSelf();
            return null;
        }
    }

    class GifEngine extends Engine {
        private final Movie gif;
        private final int duration;
        private final Runnable runnable;

        float scaleX;
        float scaleY;
        int when;
        long start;
        /////
        Globals globals= new Globals();
        private int idImagen;

        private Integer []imagenes= {R.raw.uno,R.raw.dos,R.raw.tres,R.raw.cuatro,R.raw.cinco,
                R.raw.seis,R.raw.siete,R.raw.ocho,R.raw.nueve,R.raw.diez,R.raw.once,R.raw.doce,
                R.raw.trece,R.raw.catorce,R.raw.quince,R.raw.dieciseis,R.raw.diecisiete,
                R.raw.dieciocho,R.raw.diecinueve,R.raw.veinte,R.raw.veintiuno,R.raw.veintidos,
                R.raw.veintitres,R.raw.veinticuatro,R.raw.veinticinco,R.raw.veintiseis,
                R.raw.veintisiete,R.raw.veintiocho,R.raw.veintinueve,R.raw.treinta};

        GifEngine() throws IOException {
            idImagen=globals.getIdImagen();
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(imagenes[idImagen]);

            if (is == null) {
                throw new IOException("No se puede cargar la imagen");
            }

            try {
                gif = Movie.decodeStream(is);
                duration = gif.duration();
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }

            when = -1;
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    animateGif();
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            gifHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
            if (visible) {
                animateGif();
            } else {
                gifHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
            scaleX = width / (1f * gif.width());
            scaleY = height / (1f * gif.height());
            animateGif();
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
                                     float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep,
                                     int xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset) {
            super.onOffsetsChanged(
                    xOffset, yOffset,
                    xOffsetStep, yOffsetStep,
                    xPixelOffset, yPixelOffset);
            animateGif();
        }

        void animateGif() {
            tick();

            SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = getSurfaceHolder();
            Canvas canvas = null;

            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

                if (canvas != null) {
                    gifCanvas(canvas);
                }
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }

            gifHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

            if (isVisible()) {
                gifHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000L/25L);
            }
        }

        void tick() {
            if (when == -1L) {
                when = 0;
                start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            } else {
                long diff = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                when = (int) (diff % duration);
            }

        }

        void gifCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
            gif.setTime(when);
            gif.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }
}
```

Tengo un activity de inicio el cual me envía un número de índice para elegir el wallpaper que se mostrara como fondo de pantalla, bueno al ejecutar la aplicación en el emulador se elije y establece normalmente el wallpaper pero si deseo cambiar abro la aplicación otra vez y elijo y supuestamente aplico el nuevo gif pero se mantiene el que esta no cambia nada.

¿En qué estoy fallando?

Comment: Donde recibes el número del índice que envias desde el activity?

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo de la clase `Globals`.

Comment: public class Globals {
    private static Globals instance;
    private static int idImagen;

    public int getIdImagen() {
        return Globals.idImagen;
    }

    public void setIdImagen(int t) {
        Globals.idImagen = t;
    }

    public static synchronized Globals getInstance(){
        if (instance==null){
            instance=new Globals();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

Comment: de mi activity principal le envio un valor a la variable declarada en la clase Globals (setIdImagen()), y desde la clase GIFWallpaperService leo ese valor (getIdImagen()) y lo indexo al array imagenes[]

Comment: Ya has comprobado colocando la posición manualmente `InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(imagenes[5]); `

Comment: si ya lo intente y nada, al ejecutar y colocar el gif como wallpaper la primera vez funciona pero si quiero cambiarlo no lo hace

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código con el que envías la posición desde el MainActivity?

Comment: g.setIdImagen(position); Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
 intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), GIFWallpaperService.class));

                finish();

Comment: este el codigo modificado de la clase globlals private int idImagen;


    public int getIdImagen(){
        return this.idImagen;
    }
    public void setIdImagen(int imagen){
        this.idImagen=imagen;
    }

Comment: no hay alguna forma de terminar el proceso ya que como dije cuando ejecuto la aplicacion por primera vez y aplico un gif animado como wallpaper lo hace con normalidad pero cuando quiero cambiar otro gif y hago la seleccion y establezco como fondo de pantalla este no cambia, si quiero cambiar tengo que cerrar la aplicacion y comenzar de nuevo por eso queria saber si se puede matar el proceso anterior que se ejecuta

Comment: o parar el wallpaper service o engine para poder reiniciar el mi clase y cambiar de fondo de pantalla